# How can I store references to member instances and their corresponding conversion functions in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a collection of objects, specifically a list of individuals, each with various instance variables. These variables include attributes such as name, age, and address etc. My goal is to export this list of persons into a table which should be easily expendable.

I imagine an array where I can input all the *getter* functions and then I can iterate over the array and output the corresponding result.

For example the `Person` class:

```java
public class Person
{  
  private String name
  private integer age;
  private Address address;
  // More variables
  // Getter and setters
}
```

The `Exporter` function

```java
imaginay_Array = {
                   {Person::name, convert_name()},
                   {Person::age, convert_age()},
                   {Person::address, convert_address()}
                 };


public static void export(List<Person> persons) {
  /// Write headers of table
  /// ...
  ///


  for (Person person : persons) {
    for (XXX variable : imaginay_Array) {
      writeCell(person.variable())
    }
  }
}
```

In the end I expect something like this:

| Name | Age | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 45 | 813 Howard Street Oswego NY 13126 |
| Marc | 27 | 123 Hogwarts |

And if I later need more fields exported then I can just add them to the array.

Coming from a C++ background I imagine something like a function pointer which I can store in the array.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _Coming from a C++ background_ Speaking from experience, first thing you need to do is [think in Java](https://github.com/media-lib/prog_lib/blob/master/java/Bruce%20Eckel%20-%20Thinking%20in%20Java%204th%20Edition.pdf). I suggest you look at [JavaBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans). If _JavaBeans_ is appropriate, then maybe [BeanUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) may also be helpful. By the way, as a new SO member, I recommend that you take the [tour] and visit the [help].

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _My goal is to export this list of persons into a table which should be easily_ ___expendable___ I think you mean _expAndable_ One letter difference, but two entirely different words.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote (in your question):

> I imagine something like a function pointer

As far as I know, Java does not have function pointers. Instead you create an [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

You also wrote (in your question):

> a function pointer which I can store in the array

I think you mean a [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) where the map key is the name of the attribute (in class `Person`) and the map value is an object that implements the interface.

In fact, there is already an existing interface, i.e. [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html), that is what you require. And since `Function` is a *functional* interface, it can be implemented via a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Here is a small example demonstrating the above:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Address address;

    public Person(String name, int age, Address address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Function<Person, String>> converters = new HashMap<>();
        Function<Person, String> convertName = p -> p.getName();
        Function<Person, String> convertAge = p -> String.valueOf(p.getAge());
        Function<Person, String> convertAddress = p -> p.getAddress().toString();
        converters.put("name", convertName);
        converters.put("age", convertAge);
        converters.put("address", convertAddress);
        List<Person> persons = List.of(new Person("John", 45, new Address(813, "Howard street", "Oswego")),
                                       new Person("Marc", 27, new Address(123, "", "Hogwarts")));
        Class<?> personClass = Person.class;
        Field[] fields = personClass.getDeclaredFields();
        List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            String fieldName = field.getName();
            fieldNames.add(fieldName);
        }
        for (Person person : persons) {
            for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
                Function<Person, String> lambda = converters.get(fieldName);
                if (lambda != null) {
                    System.out.println(lambda.apply(person));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

record Address(int number, String street, String city) {
    
}
```

The above code uses [records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395), only to allow me to write a bit less code. It also uses [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to get the names of all the attributes in class `Person`. It also uses [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) – which [I believe] is equivalent to *templates* in C++. It also adheres to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Running the above code produces the following:
(Java 21 on Windows 10)

```
John
45
Address[number=813, street=Howard street, city=Oswego]
Marc
27
Address[number=123, street=, city=Hogwarts]
```